# id 0x4360, rev 0x03 and package 0x01 Analog 12, Type 11 (AC), Revision 1

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom, b43

Attempted all options and ended up with going down the path to `firmware-b43-installer`.

I have a TP-Link Archer T9E AC1900 PCI-E wireless adapter

My machine is running:

Linux HerculesLinux 4.2.0-29-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 8 16:57:47 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
[ 6132.925814] bcma: bus0: Found chip with id 0x4360, rev 0x03 and package 0x01
[ 6132.925848] bcma: bus0: Core 0 found: ChipCommon (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x800, rev 0x2B, class 0x0)
[ 6132.925868] bcma: bus0: Core 1 found: IEEE 802.11 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x812, rev 0x2A, class 0x0)
[ 6132.925900] bcma: bus0: Core 2 found: ARM CR4 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x83E, rev 0x02, class 0x0)
[ 6132.925934] bcma: bus0: Core 3 found: PCIe Gen2 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x83C, rev 0x01, class 0x0)
[ 6132.925951] bcma: bus0: Core 4 found: USB 2.0 Device (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x81A, rev 0x11, class 0x0)
[ 6132.958431] bcma: Unsupported SPROM revision: 11
[ 6132.958434] bcma: bus0: Invalid SPROM read from the PCIe card, trying to use fallback SPROM
[ 6132.958435] bcma: bus0: Using fallback SPROM failed (err -2)
[ 6132.958436] bcma: bus0: No SPROM available
[ 6132.960528] bcma: bus0: Bus registered
[ 6132.966495] b43-phy3: Broadcom 4360 WLAN found (core revision 42)
[ 6132.966870] b43-phy3 ERROR: FOUND UNSUPPORTED PHY (Analog 12, Type 11 (AC), Revision 1)
[ 6132.966887] b43: probe of bcma0:1 failed with error -95
[ 6132.966931] Broadcom 43xx driver loaded [ Features: PNL ]
```

Ideas?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: hi all, after absolutely purging anything broadcom related and a number of reboots, I was able to get the 'wl' driver working.

0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:0619]
        Kernel driver in use: wl

Answer (score 2):

This has now been resolved through the removal of conflicting broadcom drivers and installing the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package that provides the `wl` driver

As a side note, `iwconfig` doesn't appear to reflect the 'AC' and 5Ghz aspect of the card:

```
0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:0619]
        Kernel driver in use: wl

wlp10s0   IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"ChateauBullow"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.452 GHz  Access Point: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```